# git clone: CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number

Tags: ssh, git-clone

I'm trying to proxy through a jumphost, for access to github, using a VM that's outside the firewall.

`git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>` works on the VM.

I setup the jumphost on my Mac laptop's .ssh/config as:

```
Host vm-proxy
    HostName <vm-ip_address>
    User centos
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id.pem

Host githubproxy
    Hostname github.com
    ProxyJump vm-proxy
```

But the clone fails from the laptop:

```
$ git clone https://githubproxy/<user>/<repo>
Cloning into '<repo>'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://githubproxy/<user>/<repo>/': error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

Versions:

```
MacOs: Catalina 10.15.6
git on laptop: 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
git on VM: 1.8.3.1
```

Comment: You're using HTTPS to clone the repository.  Try using an SSH-based URL to clone instead.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> :SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
> ```

That means you are sending TCP content (HTTPS) to an HTTP port or an SSH one, but not 443

And your [proxyjump](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-proxy-bastion-proxyjump) is for jumping to an SSH session on your VM, so it might not be a good fit for an HTTPS URL.